# Are snowflake ids generated on multiple machines sortable

Tags: id-generation, guid-generation

I am reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_ID

There are 41 bits for time epoch in each generated id. but if these ids are generated on multiple machines, but the time on each machine are not aligned. how to make sure all ids are sortable by time?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do. The ids are sortable, but why do you want to sort them?